# Question about definition of sesquilinear form

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

I am now learning sesquilinear form and I have some questions about it.

My professor's definition of sesquilinear form is the following:

> A sesquilinear form
> $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle:\mathbb{H}\times\mathbb{H}\rightarrow\mathbb{K}$ is a function satisfying:
>
> 1. $\forall x,y,z\in\mathbb{H}$, $\langle x,y+z\rangle=\langle x,y\rangle+\langle x,z\rangle$
> 2. $\forall \lambda\in\mathbb{K}\quad\forall x,y\in\mathbb{H}$, $\langle x,\lambda y\rangle=\lambda\langle x,y\rangle$
> 3. $\forall x,y\in\mathbb{H}$, $\langle x,y\rangle=\overline{\langle y,x\rangle}$
>
> A sesquillinear form is called "nondegenerate" iff $(\forall  y\in\mathbb{H}, \langle x,y\rangle=0)\iff x=0$.
>
> A nondegenerate sesquilinear form is called a scalar product.
>
> The space $(\mathbb{H},\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle)$, where
> $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is a scalar product is called a unitary
> space or a scalar product space.

Then my professor states that in the unitary space we are given the following norm $||f||^2=\langle f,f\rangle$, but I can't even justify that this norm is non-negative, I can only justify that they are all reals so far.

And my professor states that in any linear space $\mathbb{X}$ with a sesquilinear form $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_\mathbb{X}$, a subset $\mathbb{X}_0=\{f:\langle f,f \rangle=0\}$ is a linear space.

However, I don't know how to show it's closed under addition. If $x,y\in\mathbb{X}_0$, then $\langle x+y,x+y\rangle=\langle x,y\rangle+\langle y,x\rangle$, which I don't know why is zero.

Comment: Your question contains several typos. Can you fix them? Also what is a unitary space?

Comment: This is not enough to have $\left<f,f\right>\geq 0$. Indeed, take $\mathbb H=\mathbb C$ and  $\left<f,g\right>=-f\bar g$. Then $\left<\cdot ,\cdot \right>$ is a sesquilinear form, but it's not positive definite.

Comment: @QuantumSpace: As defined by the OP, unitary space=inner space.

Comment: The reason why I am so confused about this is because that's exactly what my professor wrote in his notes. I don't know which part is a typo and I don't know why my professor relaxes the positive definite property.